# Congratulations to Majenko on reaching 20k+ rep!

Tags: discussion

Our *Arduino* Stack Exchange site is humming along nicely, and it is appropriate here to congratulate **[Majenko](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/4143/majenko)** for being the first to reach 20k rep.

Well done.

Comment: @majenko  : also has over 42K reputation on Electrical Engineering (EE SE). The Electrical Engineering knowledge allows his answers here to have broader and more complete answers.  Congratulations Majenko, and thank you for the contributions.

Comment: @Marla , note that Majenko hasn't asked any questions on Arduino.SE. Bet because he knows everything already ;D

Comment: Oh, I don't know everything, but I do know everything can be found in the datasheet ;)

Comment: He's already on his way to 40K :-) ... he's a great guy, he helped me a lot so far in my journey into the Arduino.

Answer (score 14):

Thanks guys :)

I'm just happy to spread knowledge around. Knowledge is worthless if it's hoarded :P

Comment: very wise words

Comment: Well, you've hoarded quite some knowledge before spreading it ;D Which is quiet useful, because otherwise you'll spread "half-knowledge"?

Comment: And now, congratulations on getting 30k rep!

Comment: XD :) 8D ;} B[ :P