# 63k rep user answered, then downvoted, then closed question

Tags: discussion

I don't post much here because I stopped fooling around with Arduino about the time this SE was getting off the ground, so I posted my [first question today](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/56767/what-are-the-benefits-or-advantages-of-arduino-cli?noredirect=1#comment120498_56767).  And a user with lots of rep answered it, then an hour later made a snarky comment (but obviously obvious), and at some point unilaterally closed the question (aka "put on hold"), presumably because he received a downvote from someone, possibly thinking it was from me (making this retaliation).

Not sure how things work here on this SE, but that sounds like shenanigans in general, as well as on other SEs.

Interestingly (randomly?), the [4th suggested question](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2361/congratulations-to-majenko-on-reaching-20k-rep) was a congratulations to the user to reach a milestone reputation.

It's obvious from his terse messages/comments/replies that he doesn't like to explain himself, making a point to be as succinct as possible, even to the detriment of communication.

Is there something actually wrong with this question, are shenanigans afoot, or is something else going on here?  There were several other similar types questions offered in the suggested questions dialog as I wrote the question, and it should be relatively easy for proponents of this new feature to enumerate some of the benefits of it.

Comment: There is something actually wrong with the question. It's garnering opinions, asking, effectively, "what is your opinion on this thing? What's the point of it?". If you can't see the point if it, then the point is not relevant to you - so why do you care?

Comment: Questions that ask for opinions are not welcome on the site - hence the closure.  I often answer a question and then close it, because even questions that don't belong on the site deserve an answer sometimes.

Comment: the suggested questions are generated on base of your question. and you mentioned reputation

Comment: The top 3 results for a search of "benefit" are the same kind of question that I asked.  FYI, if y'all are gonna be like Stack Overflow, I'm not going to hang around.  I don't hang out over there because it's obvious they hate questions.  This is approaching the SO gordian knot of "Look at our top voted questions to understand what kinds of questions are appropriate here" && "Highly voted questions are not an indicator of valid questions [because we've changed what questions are valid over time]".

Comment: Back to the topic of this question: your brevity and circular logic aren't explaining what you're trying to say.  Obviously, if I don't immediately appreciate the apparent value of something, I probably don't understand it's utility.  That's why I'm asking people who do know why this thing is useful.  Otherwise, if it was so trivially easy to appreciate the utikity of something, I could ask Siri/Cortana/Alexa/Jeeves.

Comment: Yes, we hate questions. We don't hate problems though. Bring us your problems and we will try to solve them - that is what we are here for. What the SO sites are *not* are general discussion forums.

Comment: If you had a need for the CLI you would immediately know the benefits of the CLI. Since you don't immediately know the benefits of the CLI you obviously have no need for the CLI, and knowing the benefits would be of no interest to you since you have no need for those benefits.

Comment: The CLI is a niche facility. It is only of interest to the people who populate that niche, and those people, by virtue of being in that niche, already know the benefits.

Comment: The problem with your overgeneralization is that it applies to all features and all questions, thereby cascading the entire reason for a Q&A site out of existence, preempting not only Q&A sites or forums, but communication as a whole.

Answer (score 4):

Majenko is elected moderator. I repeat - elected. Users of Arduino SE trust him. The reputation points are well-earned with his extensive knowledge of Arduino, microcontrollers and electronics. So your accusations are wrong. Perhaps he should not put your question on hold, but it is not shenanigans.

Comment: So, what you're saying is that someone(s) elected him king and now he can do no wrong?  Must have been a tough election with a thorough background check.  Sounds more like you're describing a saint than a moderator.  Or did a watery tart give him a sword?

Comment: there were pro-term moderators until the Arduino SE was Beta 4 years or so. then the first community moderators were elected. Nick Gammon and Majenko. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135360/theres-an-election-going-on-whats-happening-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/election

Comment: I did say right from the start not to elect me and that I would be a terrible moderator. I'd be like Cartman with a badge...

Answer (score 2):

@YetAnotherRandomUser Can I suggest that you stop <strike>arguing</strike> discussing that the question shouldn't be put on hold and instead spend that energy in **improving the question so that it can be reopened**.

As the question currently stands, I stand behind Majenko's decision to put it on hold. Having said that I think it is close to being acceptable and just needs a bit of editing to get it there.

I personally found Majenko's answer very helpful, particularly the first example, as I have a project coming up involving an Arduino and Raspberry Pi. By extension, I find the question helpful - so there is potential.

Here are some guides:

- [Help Center > Asking](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/asking)
- [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)
- [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)
- [How to ask a good question for Arduino Stack Exchange](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2523/how-to-ask-a-good-question-for-arduino-stack-exchange)

Answer (score 1):

> Interestingly (randomly?), the 4th suggested question was a congratulations to the user to reach a milestone reputation.

That post is over two years old. I was congratulating Majenko for reaching a high-reputation milestone.

I can't explain how that particular question got related to yours, there doesn't seem to be any connection.

---

> So, what you're saying is that someone(s) elected him king and now he can do no wrong?

There are processes in place for dealing with rogue moderators, however I think that in this particular case there is nothing particularly insulting or unfriendly in Majenko's response.

All users, particularly moderators, are expected to abide by the [Stack Exchange Code of Conduct](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/conduct).

Moderators must abide by [additional restrictions](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators) to their behaviour.

---

To be honest, I've had questions in other parts of Stack Exchange closed by moderators, to my annoyance. :) So, it can happen to anyone (I'm a moderator here).

The more vague the question is, the more likely it is to be closed, as a general rule.

Comment: "I can't explain how that particular question got related to yours, there doesn't seem to be any connection." This title has "64k rep" and the other has "20k+ rep"

Comment: Is the suggested question here on Meta, or on the original post? Wherever it is, I can't see it now.

Comment: is here at top-right now as Linked, because it is linked in Question

Comment: It's here **now** because the OP posted a link to it. That doesn't answer or explain why the question about the 20k rep was the "4th suggested question".

Comment: yes, now it is linked, as I write in the comment. I created an answer with a picture

Answer (score 1):

to solve the mystery about suggested questions.

if you type in the title of the question and start to write the body, SE evaluates the title to find similar questions. in 190 questions on Meta, "63k rep" is very similar to "20k+ rep"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but I just can't help myself...

[image]

... so sue me...

Comment: Hahahaha that's awesome